# How to add other activities to my android project?

Tags: android

I am building an Android project where I have implemented Navigatin Drawer. The only class I have is NavigationDrawer.java*

I want that when I click the first option of the drawer to see a Login page. I have already built a project that contains only that. It has the classes MainActivity.java , LoginActivity.java (This is the launcher activity) and RegisterActivity.java

How can I use those classes now? Should I build an intent? is that enough? and Where exactly?

Comment: Show your code to understand what is wrong.

Comment: You have to use Fragment instead of Activity with a Navigation Drawer

Comment: From what I understand you have your login activity in another project ?

Comment: If you want to open activity then `Intent` is the only choice. But if you don't want to open activity then you have to go with `Fragment`.

Comment: @shaishav yes I do and I want to take those classes and integrate them in this project

Comment: Put them in a single project only and register them in the manifest.

Comment: And how do I connect them togethere? Where do i write the code of the intent? @Shaishav

Comment: Put all your java files in a single project in the `app/src/main/java` folder. The make sure each activity is registered in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on.

If you want the drawer as a navigation inside *one* application, one way would be using an activity containing your drawer and fragments for e.g. every entry of your drawer.

If you have logically multiple applications wich you like to link from your application containing the drawer you should use Intents to open these.

Comment: Can I put an intent inside the fragment?

Comment: I would recommend you reading the definitions of Intent, Fragment, Activity etc.Regarding your question: An Intent cannot be put somewhere. It's a kind of RPC mechanism. Intents can be send to a specified destination (explicit intent) or/and can have an action which can be received by everyone registering for it (implicit intent). To receive an intent within a fragment, just pass it from your activity (onNewIntent) to your fragment or register an IntentFilter.

Answer (score 0):

Intent is the way u call other activities 
U can place a button in login page for registration also 
When they click the button user will be diverted to registration class